# Best way to search for a string in a list of strings in C

Tags: c, search

I have a list of device IDs in a file and I have a list of device IDs to verify against the first list. What would be the best way to go about it? This is how I'm trying to go about it:

```
char *token, *str, *tofree;
char line[13];
tofree = str = strdup(device_list_str);
while ((token = strsep(&str, ","))) {
    printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0) {
            printf("FOUND THE DEVICE!!");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE!!"");
}
free(tofree);
```

Here, `device_list_str` is the list of devices to be searched separated by commas. Looks something like this: `b4e62d95c5cd,b4e62ddc3ffd`.

The problem for me is how do I specify exactly with this logic that the device has not been found, because the way it is now, it always prints `DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE` even after `FOUND THE DEVICE`.

**EDIT 1**: I want to use a function, but when exactly should it return `false`?

```
bool find_device(FILE *fd, char *token) {
    char line[13]; /* or some other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Put the code in a function and return when you've found something or rework your logic to not print "not found" when you do find something.

Comment: Add a boolean variable whose state tells if the device was found or not. Then after the loop check it.

Comment: regarding; `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) `  The function: `fgets()` inputs any trailing newline, so the first statement inside the body of the loop should be: `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: per your example data (which I'm thinking is the same as the data in the file.  I.E. comma separated device strings..  The array `line[[]` is only 13 characters long and `fgets()` will use the last char for the NUL terminator, so can only input 12 characters at a time.  This 'might' result in the second and following calls to `fgets()` not being properly aligned on the file contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bool flag:

```
bool found = false;
while ((token = strsep(&str, ","))) {
  printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd)!=NULL) {
    ....
    found = true;
    break;
  }
  if (found) { ...
```

But a better way is to use a function:

```
//...
while ((token = strsep(&str, ","))) {
    printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
    if (find_device(fd, token)) {
      printf("FOUND THE DEVICE!!");
    } else {
       printf("DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE!!"");
    }
} 

bool find_device(FILE *fd, char *token) {
    char line [13]; /* or some other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To read the file once, you can rearrange the original code:

```
char line[13];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
  char *token, *str, *tofree;
  tofree = str = strdup(device_list_str);
  while ((token = strsep(&str, ","))) {
    printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
        if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0) {
            printf("FOUND THE DEVICE!!");
            break;
        }
    printf("DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE!!"");
  }
  free(tofree);
}
```

but in this case you should change the function too:

```
bool find_device(char* line, char* device_list_str) {
   // ..., leaving this as an exercise
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! Please look at the edit I made on the question.

Comment: Updated. the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! and I'm currently re-looping through the file for every deviceID in device_list_str, if that's what you meant by "Do you need to rewind the file after each inner loop?". I did try to do it the other way around by reading a line from the file and comparing it against my list, but that made it kinda complicated. If you have suggestions, please let them flow :)

Comment: Updated with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to your problem:

- you can use a boolean indicator:

  ```
    char *token, *str, *tofree;
    char line[80];
    tofree = str = strdup(device_list_str);
    while ((token = strsep(&str, ",")) != NULL) {
        bool found = false;
        printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
            if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0) {
                printf("FOUND THE DEVICE!!\n");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            printf("DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE!!\n"");
        }
    }
    free(tofree);
  ```
- you can use a utility function:

  ```
    bool find_device(FILE *fd, const char *token) {
        char line[80];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
            if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
  ```

Use it this way:

```
    while ((token = strsep(&str, ","))) {
        printf("\nLOOKING FOR: %s\n", token);
        if (find_device(fd, token)) {
            printf("FOUND THE DEVICE!!\n");
        } else {
            printf("DID NOT FIND THE DEVICE!!"");
        }
    }
```

Note however that you should rewind the stream to allow for multiple tests and you should strip the trailing newline before comparing the strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool find_device(FILE *fd, const char *token) {
    char line[80];
    rewind(fd);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) != NULL) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the newline if present
        if (strcasecmp(line, token) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You might actually want to strip all initial and trailing white space.